# Automatic enum definition in C99

Tags: c, enums, c99

I would like to create an enum for the states of a DFA. The DFA has 98 states ranging from 0 to 97. The elements of the enum should look like: `q_0, q_1, ..., q_97`. How to I automatically generate this enum?

Comment: run `printf("q_0"); for (i = 1; i < 98; i++) printf(", q_%d", i);` with output set to your c file (as part of the makefile)

Comment: Enumerations are designed for defining names; they provide little type safety. There is little value in names that are largely nondescript numbers. You might just as well use an `unsigned char` with values 0 to 97.